# Print random characters from string

Tags: java

I want to print three random characters, chosen from a given string. But I have no idea how to do random things like this!

See the "Bonus Opportunity" in [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckNRS.png).

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK1Ub.png), split into 2 parts with the extra credit part being on the right side.

Comment: You can use the `Random` class to generate random integers then cast them to char (ASCII).

Comment: Paste your code in here. Voting to close for sheer laziness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is too lazy to show his code directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what "random" means in this case.

#### Weighted probability

If repeating characters should be given a higher chance of being chosen, simply concatenate the first name, middle name, and last name into one string:

```
String s = first + middle + last;
```

Then generate a random number between 0 and the length of the string:

```
Random r = new Random();
int R = r.nextInt(s.length());
```

Use this random number to index the particular character:

```
output_character = s.charAt(R);
```

Repeat as many times as desired.

#### Equal probability

If each of the characters are to have the same probability as the others, you will need to push unique characters into a list and repeat the same procedure as described above.

Comment: Oh my gosh this is great. Everything else I saw involved doing this different class thing. But I get this. I'm pretty sure I can apply this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is a little dishonest, academically, to ask for the solution to a homework question. It would be a bit less problematic if you'd do a little thinking on your own.

As @Zar mentioned in the comment above, asking something like "How do I get a random character in Java" would be simpler, and would give you what you need to answer the question without asking someone else to hand it to you.

Comment: Its just extra credit I made the needed code(its in my pic)but I want to add the random part. The reason why the teacher made it extra credit was because we havent gone over it yet. I researched online & I cant find anything that I can apply to my code, the ones I find are really advanced. Im not asking for the answer to be handed to me, I just want to know random.

Comment: I gave my code so you could see the level of coding Im on. I dont want an answer & not be able to apply it to my code. & to "if youd do a little thinking on your own" I have, theres a reason I did this after midnight, I worked all night looking for something to help me

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomAddingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(returnNewPass("abcabc"));
    //display something like:[abcabcwMS][abcabcCln][abcabc?p=]...so on

    }

    public static String returnNewPass(String oldPass){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(oldPass);
        Random ran = new Random();
        char c ;
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            c = (char)(ran.nextInt(93)+33);//ran will generate A~Z,a~z,0~9,@#$%^&*...so on
            sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This allows every character to be printed. The question asks to restrict the chosen characters to a particular string of characters.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq So if your know the ASCII table, you can just make those chars that allowed corresponding to the Integer Number.Check the ASCII Table-->Find those chars' int numbers-->Put them in random's condition